# finding specific word in array Javascript

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

```
 ["2013 Sea Ray 190 Sport",
  "2013 Sea Ray 205 Sport",
  "2013 Sea Ray 210 SLX",
  "2013 Sea Ray 220 Sundeck",
  "2013 Sea Ray 220 Sundeck Outboard"]
```

I want to go through all the objects in the array and list all the ones that include the word 'Sport' only, in this case I should only have the following list returned

```
 ["2013 Sea Ray 190 Sport",
  "2013 Sea Ray 205 Sport"]
```

How can I go about doing this using underscore.js?

Comment: Did you look at underscore.js array functions documentation ? It's basic.

Comment: Research first, ask questions later. Please share the code you've tried so far.

Comment: my list is called names. I tried `var newList = _.pluck(names, 'Sport');` but so far it returns null.

Comment: That's not what [`_.pluck`](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) is for: *"A convenient version of what is perhaps the most common use-case for map: extracting a list of property values."*. You don't have an array of objects, you have an array of strings.

Comment: look for `_.filter` here - http://underscorejs.org/#filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underscore solution using [_.filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter)

```
var data = ["2013 Sea Ray 190 Sport",
  "2013 Sea Ray 205 Sport",
  "2013 Sea Ray 210 SLX",
  "2013 Sea Ray 220 Sundeck",
  "2013 Sea Ray 220 Sundeck Outboard"];

var result = _.filter(data, function(string) {
    return string.indexOf('Sport') != -1;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You wanna `JavaScript`?

```js
function sift(element) {
  return element.match(/sport/);
}

var arr = ["spam", "spam", "nice sport", "bad sport", "spam"];
var filtered = arr.filter(sift);
alert(filtered);
```

beware @ comment, it won't work in my lovely `IE`  :(

Comment: Please precise the compatibility limit of your solution. The use of underscore.js by OP makes the alternate more compatible solution obvious.

Answer (score 0):

```
// like this:
Array.prototype.filterbystr = function ( str ) {
    var out = [];
    for ( var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++ ) {
        if ( Object.prototype.toString.call( this[i] ) === "[object String]" ) {
            ( this[i].indexOf( str ) !== -1 )
            && out.push( this[i] );
        }
    }
    return out;
};
[
  "2013 Sea Ray 190 Sport",
  "2013 Sea Ray 205 Sport",
  "2013 Sea Ray 210 SLX",
  "2013 Sea Ray 220 Sundeck",
  "2013 Sea Ray 220 Sundeck Outboard"
].filterbystr("Sport");
//
// ["2013 Sea Ray 190 Sport", "2013 Sea Ray 205 Sport"]
//
```